# Convergence in mean

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This is a very basic question, however, I can't find a definitive answer for it.

Let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of random variables.  Suppose that the limit of expectation of this sequence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mu$.  Does that imply that $(X_n)$ converges to $\mu$ in mean, i.e., that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[|X_n-\mu|]=0$?

Intuitively it seems so (by the identity of indiscernibles), but I've learned to be careful with absolute values of random variables, so hence the question to the community...

Comment: Take $X_n$ i.i.d. with $P(X_n = 1) = 1/2$ and $P(X_n = -1) = 1/2$ Then $E[X_n] \rightarrow 0$, but $E[|X_n|] = 1$ every time.

Comment: @DevenWare You should post that as an answer!

Comment: Hmmmm... great point @DevenWare, but what if $(X_n)$ are positive?

Comment: I think I'll post a different question about positive sequence $(X_n)$...

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593741/convergence-in-mean-for-the-sequence-of-positive-random-variables

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not true. Take $X_n$ to be i.i.d with $P(X_1 = 1) = 1/2$ and $P(X_1 = -1) = 1/2$.

Then $EX_n$ is always 0, but $E \lvert X_n\rvert = 1$  for every $n$.