# Convergence in mean for the sequence of positive random variables

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593715/convergence-in-mean).

Now let $(X_n)$ be a sequence of *positive* random variables.  Suppose that the limit of expectation of this sequence $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[X_n]=\mu$.  Does that imply that $(X_n)$ converges to $\mu$ in mean, i.e., that $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}\mathbb{E}[|X_n-\mu|]=0$?

[My previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/593715/convergence-in-mean) was for a general sequence of random variables, and Deven Ware showed that the above implication does not hold in the general case...

Comment: Similarly with your previous question, take $X_n$ iid, $X_n=1$ with probability $1/2$ and $X_n=3$ with probability $1/2$.

Answer (score 1):

Of course not. Try $X_n=X_1$ for every $n$, with $X_1\geqslant0$.

The [WP page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_random_variables) on the convergence of random variables might help you delineate some plausible implications in this context.